# Are expensive placebos more effective than cheap placebos?

Tags: medical-science, placebo

In a recent Undercover Economist column in the Financial Times ([The Ig Nobel prizes: in praise of ridiculous research](https://www.ft.com/content/eec04586-8b4d-11e6-8cb7-e7ada1d123b1)), Tim Harford mentioned that there has been a study showing that cheap placebos are less medically effective than expensive placebos.

This sounds slightly ridiculous, but, then, the placebo effect is fairly strange anyway.

So how strong is the real evidence? Do expensive placebos have stronger effects than cheap ones?

Comment: So the Placebo effect might just work on itself. It must be related to that pheomenon that people view more expensive things as better, even if its just a cheep thing with a large price tag.

Comment: Here is a link to the [original study](http://www.uvm.edu/~jgoldber/courses/HCOL195L/JAMA%20-%20Commercial%20Features%20of%20Placebo%20and%20Therapeutic%20Efficacy.pdf). My statistics background is not strong enough to judge how strong the evidence is.

Comment: It doesn't sound ridiculous at all, if you interpret the placebo effect as based on the patient's belief in the efficacy of the drug. People will generally assume a more expensive product as better (using price as a heuristic measure of quality); add a scalable placebo effect (the stronger the belief, the stronger the effect) and you will get a stronger placebo effect if you say the drug was more expensive.

Comment: @IMSoP There is a problem with that theory.  Recent studies have shown that a placebo can be effective even if the patient knows that what they're taking is a placebo.  So yes, the placebo effect is weird.  http://www.nhs.uk/news/2015/07July/Pages/The-placebo-effect-can-still-work-even-if-people-know-its-a-placebo.aspx

Comment: Yes, patients report that they *feel* better in certain ways (less pain, reduced nausea, etc), but that doesn't mean placebos have any real "effects". See [this related question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-the-placebo-effect-a-purely-psychological-effect?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't strong evidence that *any* placebos have objective clinical effects.

[Placebo interventions for all clinical conditions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20091554)

"We did not find that placebo interventions have important clinical effects in general". They only found some small effects on patient-reported outcomes, not objective outcomes.

Comment: An interesting finding, but not, I expect, the consensus view. Placebos are widely used as comparing treatment to *nothing* is thought to bias the result to the treatment. whether placebos have been studied independently is a different issue, though relevant.

Comment: I suspect the key word in that conclusion is *important*.  Since their overall result was "The overall pooled effect of placebo was a relative risk of 0.93 (95% confidence interval (CI) 0.88 to 0.99)" where "a value of less than 1 indicates a beneficial effect of placebo", it seems they in fact did find a statistically significant result

Comment: @matt_black Placebos control for measurement and reporting artifacts in addition to any possible clinical effect from "any treatment". It seems very plausible to me that placebos have no real effects themselves.

Comment: @matt_black I think that *is* the consensus medical view about placebos, even though they are widely misunderstood by the general public. Placebos aren't some "mind over matter" trick that somehow magically improve objectively measurable bodily symptoms, they are simply an acknowledgement that our *perception* of our own non-specific symptoms (pain/nausea/etc) is filtered through our messy mind. When you perform tests with [objectively measurable outcomes](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-the-placebo-effect-a-purely-psychological-effect?rq=1), you find placebos don't do much.

Comment: @BradC Maybe, but truly objective things are a lot more scarce than you might think. Placebos *also* affect the doctor's perception of the patient's symptoms. Otherwise medical trials would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

[This is the article](http://www.neurology.org/content/early/2015/01/28/WNL.0000000000001282) where the research results were published in. The double blind study was quite small, but the results were still significant. In other trials analogous results were found; if people have a larger expectation that a treatment will work, then the placebo effect will be stronger. E.g. in [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26164587) the effects of oxygen was compared to placebo oxygen in the treatment of high-altitude headache. It was found that the effect of the placebo oxygen was stronger, involving more biochemical pathways, if the patient had previously been given real oxygen. [See also this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4633056/).